# Phonegap BarcodeScanner plugin could work in Android project

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, barcode-scanner

I have tried to integrate the BarcodeScanner plugin to one of my Phonegap project of Android.
I have even done all the thing step by step as [the tutorial](https://github.com/phonegap-build/BarcodeScanner/tree/9270025f71891b2f46a38b7bc3d1223b4955dce2) provided by github.

The library has been imported,BarcodeScanner.java file has been imported,
[image]

barcode.js has been imported,
[image]

activity has been added to AndroidManifest.xml

the config.xml in res path has been also modified.
[image]

When I test my app with eclipse, I have gotten the error below.
[image]

By the way, I have used phonegap 2.9 and my code for using the plugin is as below.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceReady, true);

    function deviceReady() {
        var scanner = window.plugins.barcodeScanner;//note that cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner has also been tried. Same error.
        scanner.scan(
            function(result) {
                alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                    "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                    "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                    "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
            }, function(error) {
                alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
            });
    }
```

Really do not know what to do. Could you please give me any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I work out it. It is because of Phonegap's version. The version should be above 3.0.

Comment: Is barcodescanner.js has issue on phongap3.0 earliest version?

Comment: In previous version, you need to modify barcodescanner.js to make it work.

Comment: @JackHe even I got a same issue. can you please tell me how u resolved it.

Comment: @JackHe can you please share me phonegap3.0 version zip file. I am not able to find those.

Comment: @Prathyusha Please check the latest version from phonegap.com. It seems that barcodescanner plugin needs higher phonegap version