# how to get phonegap latest version

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, barcode-scanner

We started building a barcode app using Phonegap in Android, we are facing a problem with barcode.js. 
We are using phonegap 2.9.0 and barcode plugin 3.0 .We are getting a problem that `cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner` is not recognised. I read some where that I have to upgrade phonegap 3.0. But I am not able to find the version phonegap 3.0. Can anyone provide the links and docs?

Comment: which os you are using ?

Comment: ok. Please try the step which I mentioned in the answer. As per your question you are facing problem in upgrading your PhoneGap Installation to a specific version. Right ?

Comment: @Rahul no. I followed http://mayukhsaha.wordpress.com/2013/07/09/barcode-qr-code-scanner-and-encoder-using-phonegap-android-and-eclipse/ tut. I am getting issue that 'barcodeScanner' is not able to read. So I googled and I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19722668/phonegap-barcodescanner-plugin-could-work-in-android-project?rq=1 solution. He said in the answer "The version should be above 3.0." I searched for phonegap 3.0 version. But I am unable to find

Comment: Have you upgrade to 3.x ?

Comment: @Rahul here I have doubt. The people asking to upgrade phonegap version or barcodescanner plugin version? I need clarification for this

Comment: I read the answer, he solved the issue by upgrading it to version above 3.0. What's your phonegap version and BarcodeScanner Plugin version ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66646/discussion-between-prathyusha-and-rahul).

Comment: @Rahul My phonegap version is phonegap-2.9.0 and my barcodescanner plugin version is https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner this 3.0

Comment: You have to install node and the cordova/phonegap CLI as @Rahul told you. There is no zip like in 2.9.0

Comment: @jcesarmobile ok .can you please explain me clearly how to install node and cordova/phonegap.

Comment: Phonegap web exaplains it http://phonegap.com/install/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phonegap/Cordova has changed much from version 2.9 to 3.x and 4.X.

You don't install it from a zip any more from a zip, now you have to install node.js and npm and then use npm to install cordova (steps are explained in the cordova website).

I suggest you have a look at [my answer in this other post for considerations about migrating a project from phonegap 2.9 to 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25032226/how-to-upgrade-from-phonegap-2-9-to-phonegap-3-5-project-directory-could-not-be/25035441#25035441).

Comment: I am able to reach it correctly.I am feeling it bit difficult . Is this correct way to add cordova. http://learn.ionicframework.com/videos/windows-android/#

Answer (score 2):

Use `phonegap -v`

to check current installed version of phonegap, if your current installed version is not 2.9.0 then update your phonegap installation using

```
sudo npm update -g  phonegap
```

Use `npm info phonegap version` 
to check the latest version of phonegap available, if it doesn't suits your requirement then use

```
sudo npm install -g cordova@3.1.0-0.2.0
```

to installed a specific version of phonegap.

Comment: can you please tell me step by step.

Comment: phonegap 2.9 is not based on the CLI so just upgrading the CLI or the project will not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

find config.xml in you project and change this specific line, change the value to any version you want to use in your project

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.4.0" />
```

Comment: this only applies to phonegap build.